# How to Set Text above in Video on Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to Display text on Video. I press into pause key then display text above on video again I press the same key then remove display text It's possible in Roku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add Your label as a child of Your Screen/View/Scene where You also added Video Node but make sure to add it after Your Video Node in order to render the Label on top of it. So for example, in You Screen/View/Scene, Video Node should be child with the index 0 and Label should be child with index 1.
In Screen/View/Scene .xml add:

```
<Label
  id="testLabel"
  height="44"
  width="0"
  font="font:MediumBoldSystemFont"
  text = "Application Development Made Easy!"
  horizAlign = "left"
  vertAlign = "center"
  translation="[318,8]" />
```

In Screen/View/Scene .brs add: `m.testLabel = m.top.findNode("testLabel")`
Then add a `onKey` function to Screen/View/Scene .brs:

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean

  handled = false
  if press = true and key = "play"
      if videoNode.state = "playing"
        m.testLabel.visible = true
      else if videoNode.state = "paused"
        m.testLabel.visible = false
      end if
      handled = true
  end if

  return handled
end function
```

Comment: I don't understand one thing. In code, you write in a playing state true and paused state false But Its worked on pause video true and playing the video false. How It's Possible

Comment: Video node will have state playing when You first press play button(if video is playing that is). I assume you want to stop the player then and show the label. That's why I set up m.testLabel.visible = true in that case and vice versa if video node state is paused.
This is just general example on how to do it, You can tweak the code to suit your use case.